# Rabl Multi-model collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I am using RABL to output a Sunspot/SOLR result set and the search results object is composed of multiple model types.  Currently within the rabl view I have:

```
object false

child @search.results => :results do
  attribute :id, :resource, :upccode
  attribute :display_description => :description

  code :start_date do |r|
    r.utc_start_date.to_i
  end

  code :end_date do |r|
    r.utc_end_date.to_i
  end

end

child @search => :stats do
  attribute :total
end
```

The above works for a single model; however, when multiple model types are within the @search.results collection, it fails because both classes do not have the same instance methods.  Does anyone know how to have different attributes based on the type?  Ultimately, it would be nice to conditionally extend a different template within the results collection based on the type of object.  Something like the below pseudo code:

```
child @search.results => :results do |r|
  if r.class == Product
    extends "product/base"
  else
    extends "some other class base"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take full control with 'node' and avoid this issue entirely in the 'worst' case:

```
node :results do
  @search.results.map do |r|
    if r.is_a?(Product)
      partial("product/base", :object => r)
    else # render other base class
      partial("other/base", :object => r)
    end
  end
end
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Nathan -- that worked perfectly!  Really appreciate the help -- and the partial thing keeps things really clean.